# N.L. Carothers Exercise 1, Chapter 16: Proof of Uniform Convergence of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem in N.L. Carothers' *Real Analysis*:

Let $f$ be a nonnegative bounded function on $[a,b]$ with $0 \leq f \leq M$. Let 
$$E_{n,k} =\left\{\frac{kM}{2^n} \leq f < \frac{(k+1)M}{2^n}\right\},$$ for each $n = 1,2,\ldots,$ and $k = 0,1,\ldots,2^n$, and set $\phi_n = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} (kM/{2^n})\chi_{E_{n,k}}$. Prove that $0 \leq \phi_n \leq \phi_{n+1} \leq f$ and that $0 \leq f - \phi_n \leq 2^{-n}M$ for each $n$. Thus, $(\phi_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$. [Hint: Notice that $E_{n,k} = E_{n+1,2k} \cup E_{n+1,2k+1}$.]

Specifically, I'm struggling to show that $\phi_{n+1} \leq f$. I think this is where I should use the hint, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that. Thoughts or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x$ there exists a unique  $k$ such that $\frac {kM} {2^{n+1}} \leq f(x) <\frac {(k+1)M} {2^{n+1}}$. By definition $\phi_{n+1}(x)=\frac {kM} {2^{n+2}}$ and $\frac {kM} {2^{n+1}} \leq f(x)$. [Hint is required only to show that $\phi_n \leq \phi_{n+1}$]